# External JSON file is unknown type

Tags: json, actionscript-3

I've got this code where I am trying to load an JSON file and parse it. But when I try to load it with a class I've made (I can load images and sound) it gives me this error:

```
Error #2124: Loaded file is an unknown type. URL: http://192.168.1.19/Sheet1.json
```

This is the function I use for loading it, how can I make it so Flash recognizes the file type?

```
    public function LoadString(path:String) {
        var stringLoader:flash.display.Loader = new flash.display.Loader();
        stringLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(LoaderEvent.COMPLETE, loadStringComplete);
        stringLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpError,false,0,true);
        stringLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, error, false, 0 ,true);
        stringLoader.load(new URLRequest(path));
    }

    private function loadStringComplete(e:Event) {
        try {
            dispatchEvent(new LoaderEvent(LoaderEvent.STRING_LOADED,0,0,e.target.data,true));
        } catch (error:*) {
            dispatchEvent(new LoaderEvent(LoaderEvent.ERROR,0,0,"Error: "+ error.toString(),true));
        }
    }
```

The content of the JSON file is generated with the new Spritesheet method from Flash CS6.

```
{"frames": {

"Front AA0000":
{
    "frame": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":12,"h":13},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":12,"h":13},
    "sourceSize": {"w":12,"h":13}
},
"Rot AA0000":
{
    "frame": {"x":12,"y":0,"w":14,"h":6},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":14,"y":8,"w":32,"h":14},
    "sourceSize": {"w":32,"h":14}
},
"Rot AA0001":
{
    "frame": {"x":0,"y":13,"w":20,"h":8},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":9,"y":6,"w":32,"h":14},
    "sourceSize": {"w":32,"h":14}
},
"Rot AA0002":
{
    "frame": {"x":0,"y":21,"w":28,"h":8},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":4,"y":6,"w":32,"h":14},
    "sourceSize": {"w":32,"h":14}
},
"Rot AA0003":
{
    "frame": {"x":0,"y":29,"w":24,"h":8},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":4,"y":6,"w":32,"h":14},
    "sourceSize": {"w":32,"h":14}
},
"Rot AA0004":
{
    "frame": {"x":0,"y":37,"w":28,"h":11},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":3,"w":32,"h":14},
    "sourceSize": {"w":32,"h":14}
},
"Rot AA0005":
{
    "frame": {"x":0,"y":48,"w":28,"h":14},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":32,"h":14},
    "sourceSize": {"w":32,"h":14}
}},
"meta": {
    "app": "Adobe Flash CS6",
    "version": "12.0.0.481",
    "image": "Rocket AA 8-Bit.png",
    "format": "RGB8",
    "size": {"w":32,"h":64},
    "scale": "1"
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the content of `Sheet1.json`? How do you serve this file?

Comment: I edited the file with the content, and it is now just traced as a string to get it but that doesn't give the error. The error is generated with the IOError handler.

Comment: What happens when you hit `http://192.168.1.19/Sheet1.json` in your browser?

Comment: When I do that I get the JSON file as I uploaded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research on the internet I found the problem, Flash users the default loader for images, sounds and swf files. You have to use URLLoader to load other files. I used this function to successfully load text files, the LoaderEvent is a custom Event class I made to pass Strings with it:

```
public function LoadString(path:String) {
        var stringLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(path));
        stringLoader.addEventListener(LoaderEvent.COMPLETE, loadStringComplete);
        stringLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpError,false,0,true);
        stringLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, error, false, 0 ,true);
}

private function loadStringComplete(e:Event) {
        try {
            dispatchEvent(new LoaderEvent(LoaderEvent.STRING_LOADED,0,0,e.target.data,true));
        } catch (error:*) {
            dispatchEvent(new LoaderEvent(LoaderEvent.ERROR,0,0,"Error: "+ error.toString(),true));
        }
}
```